# How to binding `space` key in Sublime Text Editor using `Vintageous` plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want to know how to bind `space` key in `command-mode` using `Vintageous` plugin.

For example, I have the following keybinding to activate `command palette`:

```
  {
    "keys": ["super+shift+alt+ctrl+space"],
    "command": "show_overlay",
    "args": {
      "overlay": "command_palette"
    },
    "context": [{
      "key": "vi_command_mode_aware"
    }]
  }
```

As you can see, I use `meta` key with `space`. But my purpose is just to only use `space` key. Is it possible to do so. If I changed to `"keys": ["space"]`, the binding is defective.

I'm using Sublime Text 3 build 3095 on OSX 10.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I eventually get it done, use `" "` could do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `<space>`, [defined here](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/blob/master/vi/keys.py#L52)

```
@plugins.register(seqs.SPACE, (modes.NORMAL, ))
```